# How does אהבה mean love and give?

Tags: words, love

How does the same word אהבה, which means *love*, also mean *give*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rav Dessler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_Eliezer_Dessler) has been quoted by many as saying that the root word of אהבה is הב, which means "give" in Aramaic.

I don't have a more specific citation, but I can look for one.